# Dynamic Field Updates Within Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

In access I have created a table with four columns. The goal of this table is to be a checklist. I have allowed one column to accept nulls (my check box to be filled in as I progress). One column serves only as a unique identifier. The remaining two columns are for dates to be filled in.

I would like to be able to append to these columns dynamic data. i.e. I want to append in dates that are generated by a function that if changed at their source (a query) will be able to update after refreshing the table. Is this possible to do in access and if so how? If it can't be, is there a way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic SQL approach to this would be to not store the dates in your base table. Instead, you would just create a new query that joins your base table (ID, checkcolumn) with the date table/query (ID, date1, date2).

If you are open to using an Access 2010-specific feature you could have a data macro to check if some table data has been changed and change your table dates to match.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to append in dates that are generated by a function..."

When you run the function, run a VBA script that will append the data.  So, somewhere at the end of your function (or where you're calling your function), you could use code like this:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset ("Select * FROM YourTableName")

rec.AddNew
'Can also use rec("1stDateFieldName") = Whatever is in the first date field
rec(2) = Whatever is in the first date field      
'Can also use rec("2ndDateFieldName") = Whatever is in the second date field
rec(3) = Whatever is in the second date field  
rec.Update

rec.Close
db.Close
```

Obviously the variables need to be tweaked a bit for your unique purposes, but that should give you an idea of how to do it.